# How can I code a CSS select for one class being present and even one of a few others not?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

I have this Less code:

```
btn {
    &.answered {
        color: #bbb;
    }
}
```

How could I modify this so the color is set to #bbb only if there is a `.answered` class and if there is not a `btn-success` or `btn-danger` or `btn-warning` class?

I do realize that I could do this by adding the `btn-success`, `btn-danger` and `btn-warning` classes after this code but I really would like to find a selector that would do this for me so it does not depend on the position of the other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should chain the `:not` pseudo-selector like in the  below snippet. This will select the button when it doesn't have even one of the other 3 classes. In other words, this is equivalent to saying *exclude all elements where x OR y OR z is present.*

**Less Code:**

```css
button{
  .answered{
    &:not(.btn-success):not(.btn-warning):not(.btn-danger) {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo based on compiled output:**

```css
button.answered:not(.btn-success):not(.btn-warning):not(.btn-danger) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class='answered'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-success'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-danger'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-warning'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-warning btn-success'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-danger btn-success'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-warning btn-danger'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-warning btn-danger btn-success'>Click Me</button>
```

---

A comma separated list of `:not` selectors (grouping) would exclude only the element which has all 3 other classes. It will not work (exclude) when even one of the other class is present on the element. In other words, it is equivalent to saying *exclude all elements where x AND y AND z are present.*

You can see in the below snippet how it applies red color to all elements which don't have all the other classes together. It behaves in this way because when the element has `.btn-success`, it still doesn't have one of the other two.

```css
button.answered:not(.btn-success),
button.answered:not(.btn-danger),
button.answered:not(.btn-warning) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class='answered'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-success'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-danger'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-warning'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-warning btn-success'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-danger btn-success'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-warning btn-danger'>Click Me</button>
<button class='answered btn-warning btn-danger btn-success'>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
btn {
    &.answered:not(.btn-success):not(.btn-danger):not(.btn-warning) {
        color: #bbb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you combine those into `&.answered:not(.btn-success):not(.btn-danger):not(.btn-warning)`?

Comment: Because I've thought those 3 classes will not be present at the same time, and they should not be. But I've edited the question like you've said, so it will work either way.